Where can i check Azure App service scale up logs?
I am trying to check the logs of my Azure app. Specifically i want to search the logs that when and who scale up my App service plan. But i am not able to find any place where these logs are present.
Can someone please let me know where i can check these?
Thanks
I tried the Activity logs but Scale up or down logs were not present there.

Have you checked the Activity Log for the App Service Plan instead of the actual App Service itself?

To view the scale up and scale down logs in your Azure App Service.

In your Azure App Service =>select Monitoring => Diagnostic settings_.*



Click on + Add diagnostic setting.
Here you can select your required destination details to send logs.
I've used log analytics workspace.
Under logs, make sure HTTP Logs, App service console logs, App service application logs are checked.
Save the changes.


After doing above changes, I've scaled up my service plan and can view the changes in activity log of my app service.


You can also view the logs using Azure CLI.

I have referred this MSDoc for the CLI command.


az monitor activity-log list --resource-group YourRGName --resource-id /subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/YourRGName/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/AppServicePlan --query "[?operationName.value=='Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/write']"




Caller displays the username of the person who scale up or scale down the Azure app service.
LocalizedValue shows what changes have been done.


@HIMS Sharma Is your issue resolved?
